# Doctrine dql with left join using the same table

Tags: doctrine-orm, left-join, dql

I am trying to transform the following query to dql:

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM conversation__conversation cc
INNER JOIN conversation__message cm 
  ON cm.conversation_id = cc.id
INNER JOIN vehicle__vehicle vv 
  ON vv.id = cc.vehicle_id
WHERE (cc.driver_id = 25 OR vv.owner_id = 25)
  AND cm.id in (SELECT m1.id
                FROM conversation__message m1 
                LEFT JOIN conversation__message m2
                  ON m1.conversation_id = m2.conversation_id AND m1.id < m2.id
                WHERE m2.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY cm.created_at DESC;
```

I see 2 main difficulties in this query. The first one is that you have a subselect, but I already check how to do it in dql but the really difficult part is to make a left join using the same table. I cannot make it work... anyone knows how to do it?